# WSLENV fails to set JAVA_HOME in Windows Subsystem for Linux

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

In PowerShell I've verified that my JAVA_HOME is set:

`Get-Item Env:JAVA_HOME`

```bash
Name                           Value
----                           -----
JAVA_HOME                      C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-11.0.15.10-hotspot
```

I used WSLENV to share this var:

`setx WSLENV "JAVA_HOME/p"`

Yet when I enter `wsl` and type `env`, `JAVA_HOME` is nowhere to be found

I've looked at other posts and help articles and have not found anything of help.

I tried exporting the variable from my `~/.profile` file too:

`export JAVA_HOME="/mnt/c/Program Files/Eclipse Adoptium/jdk-11.0.15.10-hotspot/"`

Which "works" except when I try to run gradle it errors saying the JAVA_HOME is an invalid directory... except it's not because I can `cd` to it.

I can get it to work for the current session by setting the env variable like this: `$env:WSLENV="JAVA_HOME/p"`

But that doesn't persist between sessions.