# PATH with spaces errors on WSL when passed via WSLENV

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have a windows environment variable for JAVA_HOME:

```
PS > Get-Item Env:JAVA_HOME   

Name                           Value
----                           -----
JAVA_HOME                      C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-11.0.15.10-hotspot
```

I have WSLENV to share env variables with WSL/Ubuntu:

`$env:WSLENV="JAVA_HOME/p"`

I've verified that the path is being changed properly

```
$ env | grep JAVA
JAVA_HOME=/mnt/c/Program Files/Eclipse Adoptium/jdk-11.0.15.10-hotspot
```

I can `cd` to that directory, although with quotes around it.

Yet when I try run a gradle command, I get:

```
[gradle] ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: /mnt/c/Program Files/Eclipse Adoptium/jdk-11.0.15.10-hotspot
```

I'm sure it's the spaces, but I don't know how I'm supposed to force it to use quotes? Wouldn't `WSLENV` and `/p` have done that already?

Wrapping the env var in quotes in windows does nothing.

Comment: Avoid posting [duplicate questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77073250/11317272).

Comment: Where are you running the `gradle` command? In WSL distro's bash terminal?

Comment: @msrumon This is not a duplicate. This is about the variable failing to be passed when set using `setx`. The other is about spaces not being encoded.

Comment: @msrumon In the wsl terminal, yes. Trying out `bun` instead of `yarn` and we have a java backend so we boot vite and gradle.

Comment: Is `gradle` expecting `JAVA_HOME` in Windows path format, like C:\Program... ?